# Remove specified element from a key HashTable c++

Tags: c++, pointers, hashtable

Hello i want to remove a specified element from a key in a hashtable but the function i have, deletes the last value i inserted into the key.I need two arguments into my function.For example i want to delete the element 3 from the key 1.

Key:1 Elements:2 4 3

Key:2 Elements: 5 6 7

After remove(e.g Remove(1,3)) i want something like this Key:1 Elements:2 4

```
void HashTable::Remove(int key)
{
    int hash_val = HashFunc(key);
    HashNode* entry = htable[hash_val];
    HashNode* prev = NULL;
    if (entry == NULL || entry->key != key)
    {
        cout<<"No Element found at key "<<key<<endl;
        return;
    }
    while (entry->next != NULL)
    {
        prev = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    if (prev != NULL)
    {
        prev->next = entry->next;
    }

    delete entry;

    cout<< "Element Deleted" <<endl;
}
```

Any ideas?

I tried this but it doesn't work always.

```
void HashTable::Remove(int key,int value)
{
    int hash_val = HashFunc(key);
    HashNode* entry = htable[hash_val];
    while (entry != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->key == key)
        {
            if(entry->value == value)
            {
                delete entry;
                break;
            }
       // cout<<entry->value<<" ";
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need two arguments into my function." Puzzled. You know this, so why have you only specified one? Two seems like the logical place to start.

Comment: what did you see when you stepped though your program line by line using a debugger?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I gonna put two arguments but I have no idea how to adjust the function.

Comment: `[help-me]` `delete entry;` in your `HashTable::Remove` looks awfully suspicious. Don't you need to adjust various pointers to actually remove the entry from the list?

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes but sometimes works, sometimes not..I know it's suspicious

Comment: @Tommys, sorry, I was too gentle there. It's not "suspicious", it's wrong. Look at what the "regular" remove does with pointers and do something similar.

Comment: Emphasizing Arkadiy's point with an example. Say you have linked A, B, and C into A->B->C->end in the table. When you remove B you will get A->undefined. You want A->C->end. The best way to resolve linked list problems is to visualize the problem by drawing pictures.

Comment: Ok i fixed this, but i can't delete the first node of the hashtable.If the value is on another postition there is no problem, but when it's on the first it still stays there.